# Android: Webview is not scrolling with the content of page

Tags: android, xml, webview

I am using webview in my layout which is occupying top half of the screen.
Other content of data is coming in down half screen.
Data is huge so scroll is coming for that but problem is only down half portion is scrolling and top half portion where is created webview is not scrolling.
I want to stick that webview to top of the screen so it will also scroll and scroll I can see new data in full screen.

My Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navMainLayout">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_menu"
    android:id="@+id/drawerClickBtn"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerClickBtn" />
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/qblebelId"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawerClickBtn"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/drawerClickBtn"
        android:textColor="@color/AppThemeColor"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:text="Question Bank"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/expertAnswerlistId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qblebelId"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navDrawerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar_expand"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Guys if you have confusion, ask me. I can provide more details.

Comment: I can't see any half webview. Please explain clearly

Comment: I gave height of the webview because of that it is coming on half of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful to you:

```
WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
v.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
v.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This provides scroll inside webview but I want outside webview. In full layout.

Answer (score 1):

May be help you try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/navMainLayout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_menu"
    android:id="@+id/drawerClickBtn"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawerClickBtn" />
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/qblebelId"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawerClickBtn"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/drawerClickBtn"
    android:textColor="@color/AppThemeColor"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:text="Question Bank"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/expertAnswerlistId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/qblebelId"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />



  <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/content_frame"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/navDrawerView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <include
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     layout="@layout/tool_bar_expand"/>

   <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/nav_left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" >
   </ExpandableListView>
   </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am not able to see any change. What you modified in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="160dp"
```

Comment: Ok, I am trying this.

Comment: Same problem, Webview is not scrolling with other content of screen.